# unable to resubscribe to behaviorsubject after reloading component for second use

Tags: angular, typescript

I've read that you should always unsubscribe when removing a component. In my case this happens when another childroute gets activated and thus another childcomponent takes the place of the previous component. When i navigate back to the first component i get the error `object unsubscribed` even though i am subscribing to the behaviorsubject again. The only way to prevent this error is by removing the unsubscribe code from ngOnDestroy, but then the behaviorsubject never gets unsubscribed. So I am rather confused. When exactly should i unsubscribe? If it is not when removing a child component then when is it? Here is my code:

```
export class TemperatureSettingsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  data: any;
  temperatureForm: FormGroup;
  monthlyTemperatureCurve: number[];
  saveToLocalStorage:BehaviorSubject<any[]> = this.seedCalendarService.getSaveBehaviorSubject();
  useImperialMeasureSystem: boolean = true;
  options = {
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  };
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
  private seedCalendarService: SeedCalendarService,
  private notificationService: NotificationService,
  private dataStoreService: DataStoreService) {
    this.saveToLocalStorage.subscribe(pair => {
      if(pair[0] === DataType.MEASURE_SYSTEM_PREFERENCE){
          this.useImperialMeasureSystem = pair[1]; 
      }
    });
    this.temperatureForm = fb.group({
      'january' : [''],
      'february' : [''],
      'march' : [''],
      'april' : [''],
      'may' : [''],
      'june' : [''],
      'july' : [''],
      'august' : [''],
      'september' : [''],
      'october' : [''],
      'november' : [''],
      'december' : ['']
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.saveToLocalStorage.unsubscribe();
  }
```

You can clearly see that i am resubscribing to the behaviorsubjet toLocalStorage in the constructor, but it seems only the first instance of a child component is allowed to subscribe and unsubscribe. Every consecutive instance of the child component that is being loaded is not able to resubscribe and i find this very confusing because it is a new instance. Please clarify, thank you.

Comment: Calling `unsubscribe` on a subject renders it closed and no longer usable. Have a look at [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-closed-subjects-1b6f76c1b63c).

Comment: and the events object of Router, I can unsubscibe and then resubscribe to the object whenever i choose, is this object different to a subject?

Comment: If you subscribe to an observable and receive a subscription, yes, you can call `unsubscribe` on the subscription. It's only subjects that are a special case. And `Subject.prototype.unsubscribe` is likely to be removed in RxJS v7; it's confusing - as it has nothing to do with subscriptions; it's more closely related to the concept of disposal in other Rx implementations - and not especially useful.

Comment: ok, so to summarize what you just said. You can subscribe and unsubscribe then resubscribe to an observable as often as you'd like whereas a BehaviorSubject can only be unsubscribed once. When you call unsubscribe() from somewhere in the program the Behaviorsubject becomes inaccessible to all subscribers. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, calling `unsubscribe` on a `Subcription` to anything - even a subject - is totally fine, but calling `unsubscribe` **directly** upon a subject will close/dispose/destroy that subject. It's such an unlikely thing to want to do that I wrote a TSLint rule to disallow it: [`rxjs-no-subject-unsubscribe`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules).

Comment: ok, and must i unsubscribe the subscription everytime when i remove a child component that subscribed to a subject? Or will the act of removing the component also destroy the subscription of that component to the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your child components are subscribing to the BehaviorSubject in the parent component, they will lose this subscription as soon as you navigate away from the parent component - aka. when it gets destroyed. Your first child is likely on the same DOM as your parent so it doesn't get affected but your second child is likely isn't, so it loses access to this Subject.

The solution to this is leave the BehaviorSubject in the service and have your parent/children subscribe to that instead.